# Get coefficient names or visualize structure of MLPRegressor from sklearn.neural_network

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression

I'm working with MLPRegressor from the python sklearn neural network library but I don't understand how to apply the result or weights to the data I get in the future. I know the predict function is coded for that itself but I'm using it to calibrate a hardware and cannot use python in that. So I want to know how to use to apply the coefficients I get from the coefs_ function. I found the source code using the inspect library but couldn't understand it properly. To be clear I want know if there is something in sklearn.neural network like PolynomialFeatures.get_feature_names()

Comment: there is not something like PolynomialFeatures.get_feature_names()  for MLPRegressor . Can you be more specific about what you want to do?

Comment: I basically want to do a forward pass on any new data I get. As I've already told I have to use it for calibrating a hardware and can only use C++ in that. My original plan was to train a neural network in Python and obtain the weights for predicting results for new data on my own. So I just want to know the order of the coefficients that one gets from the coefs_ function @sera

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the model `coefs_` and `intercepts_` after training to get the weights and biases. Weights/biases are nested arrays where each sub-array is the weights/biases for the ith layer.

```py
mod1 = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(2,) # 1 hidden layer with 2 nuerons
                    ).fit(X, y)

mod1.coefs_
>>> [array([[-0.07291121,...1669999]]), array([[-0.70564918]...425659 ]])]
mod1.intercepts_
>>> [array([-0.86526782, ...05634334]), array([-0.10166917])]
```

Since this is only one hidden layer and one output layer, you will get two nested arrays which you can subset on to get your final weights and biases accordingly.
From the attributes section of the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html).